# How to reset a quest or zone

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

Is there a way to reset a quest or area in Azerothcore such that the quest giver or quest objectives are at their initial states?

I've encountered some problems when a player completes a quest that is not resetting, thereby preventing other players from doing the quest. One such quest is Torek's Assault in Ashenvale. After quest completion, the quest NPCs do not respawn at their starting positions to enable other players to perform the same quest.

Another type of problem is when a player completes the Hellfire Fortifications quest by capturing the three outposts in Hellfire Peninsula. In a server where all players are playing the same faction, only the first one gets to complete the quest. Is there any way to put the outposts back to neutral as a GM? If not, could it be done by modifying the database?

Answer (score 3):

### You don't reset the quest zone to achieve what you wish.

#### All of your issues seem to be related with creature scripting instead of zone bugs.

Each of your issues can be broken down into these 2 points:

1. > Torek's Assault in Ashenvale. After quest completion, the quest NPCs do not respawn at their starting positions to enable other players to perform the same quest.

Your problem is that you need to despawn your desired NPCs. You need to get the closest creature entry within a certain radius and start despawning out of combat every x seconds if this is done via SmartAI. With core scripts you would need to iterate through all the found creatures and despawn them.

2. > Another type of problem is when a player completes the Hellfire
   >   Fortifications quest by capturing the three outposts in Hellfire
   >   Peninsula. In a server where all players are playing the same faction,
   >   only the first one gets to complete the quest

Is this creature's script Smart AI or core script? Is the event on repeat? Is the creature correctly scripted?

Comment: For the first problem it is likely a bug that the quest NPC does not despawn automatically upon quest completion. I am assuming that there is already some script setup for this type of situation, but I do not know enough about the azerothcore inner workings.

The second problem is that the Hellfire Fortifications are specific areas in the zone, not creatures, that when captured (by staying there for x amount of time) are attuned to one faction until they are captured by the other faction. This is by design, but with all players in the same faction, this does not allow repeating.

Comment: If you think there's a bug, open up an issue on the repository so people can test and confirm it with more detailed information. This script doesn't seem to have been updated for long and it could contain old bugs https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/scripts/OutdoorPvP/OutdoorPvPHP.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Look at the command table and our wiki, maybe there is a command for that.

Otherwise you could delete something in the Db probably but again I'm not really versed in the subject, just trying to give you some hints.

What you should do is try to do the quest alone on a dev server, see before and after, what data has been inserted, then delete it to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a SAI for that creature. Make him to respawn at location where you want ( With the timer, or on quest taken/complete